# How to get the length of the contents of a varbinary field with SQL in Advantage Database Server db?

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the length of the contents of a varbinary field using SQL with Advantage Database Server V11?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious function to look for would be `LENGTH(field)` or `LEN(field)` (see [online help](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage12/master_string_functions.htm)).

If those only work on character fields, then you can always cast.

Comment: Thanks for that. I hadn't though of using cast.

Comment: For MSSQL `LEN` works while `LENGTH` doesn't (not a valid function name).